# How to simplify A + 0 > 0 into A > 0?

Tags: coq, simplification

I'm just a beginner with Coq, and I've been trying to prove a few elementary theorems about natural numbers. I've done a few already, not very elegantly, but completed nether the less. However I'm totally stuck on completing this theorem:

```
Theorem add_increase: (forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b).
Proof.
  intros A.
  intros B.
  intros H.
  case B.
```

Entering this in, I get this output:

```
2 subgoals
A, B : nat
H : A > 0
______________________________________(1/2)
A + 0 > 0
______________________________________(2/2)
forall n : nat, A + S n > S n
```

Obviously, the first goal is pretty trivial to simplify to hypothesis `H`. However, I just can't figure out how to make this straightforward simplification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to simplify this is to use a rather boring lemma

```
Lemma add_zero_r : forall n, n + 0 = n.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n. reflexivity.
  simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

and next use this to rewrite your goal:

```
Theorem add_increase: (forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b).
Proof.
  intros A.
  intros B.
  intros H.
  case B.
  rewrite (add_zero_r A).
  assumption.
```

To finish the other proof case I've used a little lemma and a tactic that eases the task of proving stuff with inequalities over naturals.

First, I've imported `Omega` library.

```
Require Import Omega.
```

Prove another boring fact.

```
Lemma add_succ_r : forall n m, n + (S m) = S (n + m).
Proof.
  intros n m. induction n. reflexivity.
  simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

and going back to `add_increase prove` we have the following goal:

```
A, B : nat
H : A > 0
============================
forall n : nat, A + S n > S n
```

That can be solved by:

```
 intros C.
 rewrite (add_succ_r A C).
 omega.
```

Again, I've used the previous proved lemma to rewrite the goal. The `omega` tactic is a very useful one since it is a complete decision procedure for the so called [quantifier free Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), and based on your context, it can solve the goal `automagically`.

Here's the complete solution to your proof:

```
 Require Import Omega.

 Lemma add_zero_r : forall n, n + 0 = n.
 Proof.
   intros n. induction n. reflexivity.
   simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
 Qed.

 Lemma add_succ_r : forall n m, n + (S m) = S (n + m).
 Proof.
  intros n m. induction n. reflexivity.
  simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
 Qed.

Theorem add_increase: (forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b).
Proof.
  intros A.
  intros B.
  intros H.
  case B.
  rewrite (add_zero_r A).
  assumption.
  intros C.
  rewrite (add_succ_r A C).
  omega.
 Qed.
```

Comment: Wow, that's an amazingly complete answer. Thank you for taking the time to help a beginner like myself. One question though, is there a way to control the name of the hypothesis created by proving the first induction subgoal? Specifically, in  add_zero_r, after the first line, a new hypothesis named "IHn" is created, is there any way to assign that hypothesis an explicit name?

Comment: Yes. You can change the name of `IHn` to `IHn1` using `induction n as [| n1 IHn1]`.

Answer (score 4):

Several common lemmas such as `a + 0 = a` etc. are put in the hint database `arith`. With them, `auto` can usually solve many simple goals of this kind, so use `auto with arith.`

```
Require Import Arith.
Theorem add_increase: (forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b).
  destruct a; intros b H.
  - inversion H.  (* base case, H: 0 > 0 *)
  - simpl. auto with arith.
Qed.
```

To see which lemmas `auto` used, you can `Print add_increase.`  In this case, `auto` used three lemmas, and they can alternatively be given explicitly to auto by `auto using gt_le_S, le_lt_n_Sm, le_plus_r.`

In general, when you need a lemma that you think ought to have already been proven, you can search for it with `SearchAbout`.  Use `_` as a wild card, or `?a` as a named wild-card. In your case above you wanted something about adding a zero on the right, so

```
SearchAbout ( _ + 0 =  _ ).
```

returns

```
plus_0_r: forall n : nat, n + 0 = n
NPeano.Nat.add_0_r: forall n : nat, n + 0 = n
```

You can even find a lemma in the library that is close to what you want to prove.

```
SearchAbout ( _ >  _ -> _ + _ > _ ).
```

finds

```
plus_gt_compat_l: forall n m p : nat, n > m -> p + n > p + m
```

which is pretty close to `add_increase`.

```
Theorem add_increase: (forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b).
  intros.
  pose (plus_gt_compat_l a 0 b H) as A.
  repeat rewrite (plus_comm b) in A.
  apply A.
Qed.
```

Comment: `a+0=a` not `0`...

Comment: @CharlieParker Oops! :-) Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using a different natural numbers library `ssrnat` and the ssreflect proof language (which is needed by the library):

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat seq.

Theorem add_increase a b : 0 < a -> b < a + b.
Proof. by rewrite -{1}[b]add0n ltn_add2r. Qed.
```

The `ltn_add2r : (m + p < n + p) = (m < n)` lemma is proved by induction on `p`, directly by induction on `p` plus commutativity and other easy properties of addition.

Comment: You should add that this is using the ssreflect library, not vanilla Coq

Comment: Oh sure, I'll be more specific than "using a different natural numbers library"

Answer (score 0):

Note that if we're invoking the `omega` tactic, we could've just done:

```
Theorem add_increase : forall a b: nat, a > 0 -> a + b > b.
Proof. intros a b. omega. Qed.
```